# AWS Java CDK setting up a RDS instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I'm in the process of learning the Java CDK, and have been tasked with setting up a postgresql RDS instance. I am having trouble finding some examples that go through how to do this.
The only example I can find is in the docs:

```
declare const vpc: ec2.Vpc;
const instance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'Instance', {
  engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.oracleSe2({ version: rds.OracleEngineVersion.VER_19_0_0_0_2020_04_R1 }),
  // optional, defaults to m5.large
  instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE3, ec2.InstanceSize.SMALL),
  credentials: rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret('syscdk'), // Optional - will default to 'admin' username and generated password
  vpc,
  vpcSubnets: {
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT,
  }
});
```

So I assume I would change the engine to postgresql, but would I need to make any other adjustments?
Am I correct in assuming this is also only the instance, and I would need some IAC to create the cluster?

If anyone has any good resources they can share for the Java CDK that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the Java link at the top of any CDK documentation page, you will get the Java documentation for that construct.

[image: TypeScript CDK documentation for DatabaseInstance]

Here is the Java documentation for [DatabaseInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/java/index.html?software/amazon/awscdk/services/rds/DatabaseInstance.html).

And yes, this construct will only create the instance. If you want a cluster, create multiple instances and connect them, or use [DatabaseCluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/java/index.html?software/amazon/awscdk/services/rds/DatabaseCluster.html).